# Does C# have anything similar to Java's String.valueOf();?

Tags: java, c#

I am looking over some code in ***Java*** here:

```
public String Build(String Str) {
    Stack<Character> result = new Stack();

    for (char x: Str.toCharArray()) {
        if (x != '$')
            result.push(x);
        else
            result.pop();
    }

    return String.valueOf(result); // Does C# have an equivalent for this?
}
```

Here's the working solution I wrote in ***C#***, but I was wondering if theres an easier method?

```
public string Build(string s) {
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    
    foreach (char x in s.ToCharArray()) {
        if (x != '$') {
            stack.Push(x);
        }
        else
            stack.Pop();
    }
    
    string result = String.Empty;
    
    while (stack.Count != 0) {   // In C#, I loop and store the value in a string.
        result += stack.Peek();
        stack.Pop();
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Is there a better method in C# that would be similar to the first method posted in Java? I understand the method in C# is returning the string backwards, but that does not matter for the functionality of this method.

Answer (score 3):

The string constructor accepts `char[]`, so that's probably what I'd use. You should also declare your stack to be of type `Stack<char>`.

```
  return new string(stack.ToArray())
```

Comment: OP will probably need to make it a `Stack<char>` rather than a non-generic `Stack` though.

Comment: For sure, it's been so long since I've used the .NET 1.0 stack my mind just inserted the generic.

Comment: Good answer @JohnV! However, ```stack.ToArray()``` will create an unnecessary copy of ```stack```. If this function is being called often, it will generate a lot of garbage.

Comment: @Tommy If this function is being called often it shouldn't use a Stack at all. A dynamically sized collection would have far more effect on application performance than .ToArray(). The string constructor is probably the fastest way to create a string outside of using a StringBuilder, which would just make the code harder to read. For average lengths strings, this will probably outperform string.Join

Comment: @JohnV Yes, ```String```'s constructor is very efficient because it simply copies the characters from the array.

Comment: @JohnV ```StringBuilder``` is very fast. That is exactly why using ```String.Join()``` is usually better, since ```String.Join()``` uses ```StringBuilder```. Please take a look at the source code of ```String``` here: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs Notice that ```String.Join()``` does not even create a new ```StringBuilder``` instance every time it's called, but uses a cached ```StringBuilder``` instance in the internal static class ```StringBuilderCache```. Also, ```String.Join()``` works with any type, not just char.

Comment: "works with any type" is not a performance advantage. OP didn't post a generic stack processing routine, it's a string processor. New string(char[]) will be faster **and** use less memory because it doesn't use a StringBuilder. The builder will have to be constantly resized to accommodate the growing string, and that's slow (relative to a straight copy.) https://dotnetfiddle.net/z9mnLj

Answer (score 2):

In c#, you can use `string.Join<T>()` to join a collection.

This method can also be used with collections of ints, floats, doubles, strings... -- or any type that uses `ToString()`.

MS Doc on "String.Join()": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0

---

In your case:

```
  public string Build(string s) {
    Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>(); // USE GENERIC HERE
    
    foreach (char x in s.ToCharArray()) {
        if (x != '$') {
            stack.Push(x);
        }
        else
            stack.Pop();
    }
    return string.Join<char>("", stack);
  }
```

Note that you need to use the generic version of Stack for this to work.
Basically, use `Stack<char>` instead of `Stack`.

***It's almost always better to use `Stack<T>` instead of `Stack` if you know the type of `T`. That is because `Stack.Peek()` returns `object`, meaning that you might get type errors when casting if you are not careful; however, `Stack<T>.Peek()` returns `T`, so it's usually safer to use `Stack<T>`.***

In this case, `T` is "char"

---

If you haven't already, you need to write this at the top of your file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

MS Doc on "System.Collections.Generics": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-6.0